# Why does only my PC encounter "This site can’t be reached - refused to connect" but any other device can access my website normally?

Tags: ip, connection-refused, ionos

I bought a domain on IONOS. I got everything working fine, but at some point I must have done something because now if I try to access my website from my PC, I get:

[image: This site can't be reached]

But I can access my website from any other device. If I use a VPN on my PC, then I can access my website. What could I have done to produce this behaviour?

I don't have any proxies enabled, I've cleared my cache on chrome, although this happens on any browser, I've flushed my DNS cache and I've disabled my firewall but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try:

Clear your cookies and cache.

Add it to your etc/hosts file, doing so will override your the DNS mapping.